# Hangfire Failing To Build For Integration Test

Tags: c#, integration-testing, xunit, hangfire, .net-7.0

I am new to integration testing. My .Net 7 WebApi uses Hangfire and it is failing to build when the CustomWebApplicationFactory is called. I am using xUnit to do the tests.

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
    public Mock<IAnimals> animals { get; }

    public CustomWebApplicationFactory()
    {
        animals = new Mock<IAnimals>();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);

        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddSingleton(animals.Object);
            services.AddLogging(builder => builder.AddConsole().AddDebug());
        });
    }

}
```

The error I get is:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.dll
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.dll but was not handled in user code
The server has not been started or no web application was configured.
```

My logging statement services.AddLogging() outputs this as the error:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Hangfire.PostgreSql.dll
```

In program.cs my hangfire config is:

```
 var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("PostgreSQLConnection");
 builder.Services.AddHangfire(config => config
   .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
     .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
     .UseStorage(new PostgreSqlStorage(connectionString)
 ));
```

Any help is appreciated!

I don't really intend to test the Hangfire jobs, but I do need to test other services.
Is there a way to get hangfire to build (maybe an in-memory database?) or to just mock hangfire or skip it?

**Update:**

I have tried to configure Hangfire and Entity as in-memory databases... something is still not quite right...

```
     builder.ConfigureServices(services => {
      // Configure Entity In-Memory database
      services.RemoveAll(typeof(AppDbContext));
      services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "IntegrationTestDb_" + DateTime.Now.ToFileTimeUtc()));

      services.RemoveAll(typeof(GlobalConfiguration));
      services.AddHangfire(config => config
         .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
         .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
         .UseMemoryStorage());
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run in to the same problem recently, and end up with this solution:

```
    var hangfireGiblets = collection
        .Where(s => s
            .ServiceType.FullName
            ?.Contains("hangfire", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == true)
        .ToArray();

    foreach (var hangfirePart in hangfireGiblets)
    {
        collection.Remove(hangfirePart);
    }

    collection.AddSingleton(Mock.Of<IGlobalConfiguration>())
        .AddSingleton(Mock.Of<JobStorage>())
        .AddSingleton(Mock.Of<IUpdateVendorDataJobsScheduler>())
        .AddSingleton(Mock.Of<RouteCollection>());
```

Comment: Thanks. My solution was just to not use the in-memory database. Move all database calls into a Repo and mock it's response rather than try and test the database.